# Macbook pro crashes occasionally on dual monitor

Tags: display

I'm using a Macbook pro 13' mid 2010 running OS X Lion 10.7.5. I just got a Viewsonic 24' monitor (2450wm-LED), and I connect it to my mbp using a miniport to VGA adapter ([this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0081XI2Y4) on Amazon). However when I plug into my mbp, I got some occasional crashes which lead to hard reboots.

I'm using it as a second monitor, i.e. with my laptop lid open. For from 30min to many hours it works fine, then suddenly I got a grey screen (or white, yellow, blue screen) on both (my laptops and the extra) monitors.

The graphics is `NVIDIA GeForce 320M 256 MB graphics`.

I tried to do a trouble shoot of my own but doesn't work. According to [this](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1237) my firmwares are updated. Using my friend's adapter leads to similar crash, using her monitor (Viewsonic 2431wm) and my adapter leads to similar crash too. Now I think it must be something wrong with my laptop, not the monitor or adapter.

Has anyone here experienced similar situation? What shall I do? Will using a DVI adapter instead of a VGA one help?

Answer (score 1):

1. Upgrade your NVIDIA driver according to your OSX version: http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/306535-nvidia-web-driver-updates-for-el-capitan-update-06232016/
2. After restart you'll see an NVIDIA icon on top right of your desktop
3. Chose 'OS X Default Graphics Driver'